# Sort dictionary by multiple values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the dictionary `{'Bill': 4, 'Alex' : 4, 'Bob' : 3, "Charles": 7}`

I need to sort this dictionary first numerically, then within that, alphabetically. If 2 items have the same number key, they need to be sorted alphabetically.

The output of this should be `Bob, Alex, Bill, Charles`

I tried using lambda, list comprehension, etc but I can't seem to get them to sort correctly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with key function (order by value (`d[k]`) first, then key `k`):

```
>>> d = {'Bill': 4, 'Alex' : 4, 'Bob' : 3, "Charles": 7}    
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda k: (d[k], k))
['Bob', 'Alex', 'Bill', 'Charles']
```

Comment: How would I do one value descending and the other ascending?

Comment: @AlexStewart, For numerical value, you can control that with negation (`-`) for descending. For non-numerical value, you should define subclass with `__lt__` defined.

Comment: @AlexStewart, You can also think of the reverse. Keep the continuous value positive and then put reverse=True into the sorted method.

`sorted(d, key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 10):

Sort on the dictionary's items (which are tuples) using `sorted()`. You can specify the sort key which will be by the dictionary's values, and then its keys:

```
>>> d = {'Bill': 4, 'Alex' : 4, 'Bob' : 3, "Charles": 7}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
[('Bob', 3), ('Alex', 4), ('Bill', 4), ('Charles', 7)]
>>> [t[0] for t in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))]
['Bob', 'Alex', 'Bill', 'Charles']
```